# Does React render the WHOLE component if only one part of the component changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am wondering if my code will be more performant if I split my large component up into many really tiny components, so that the app only renders smaller portions of the DOM at a time.

But I feel that React may already only render the portion of the app that changed, regardless of if the component is massive or tiny. So if a tiny part of a massive component is changed, React will only re-render that tiny portion of the component, and not the whole component.

Is my assertion in the second paragraph correct, or can I get better performance by splitting a large component into many small ones? I'm including both ReactJS and React Native in this question. I assume they're the same in this aspect but if they differ I would like to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I been immersing my self in React, so I hope my understanding is valid.  React uses a virtual DOM to optimize rendering of the actual DOM.  Essentially diffing the two and only patching the DOM with differences. So I believe your assertion is correct.

In regards to breaking up your large component, I think it all depends on **state** and what your component looks like.  These are the question I would ask myself: Are there multiple UI units that can stand alone and be encapsulated into a component? How much of my component is actually affected by a **state** change?

My understanding is that the component will not re-render unless there is a **state** change.  React provides a lifecycle hook **`shouldComponentUpdate`**, which does not affect it's child components, so that developers can control the rendering of the component on ***state change***.  Therefore, if there are many JSX elements that do not change, it is better to ***extract into a component the elements that are affected by state change***.  I believe that we can gain performance by not having the virtual DOM update with items that do not change.

While writing up this answer, I googled and found this blog entry: [React is Slow, React is Fast: Optimizing React Apps in Practice](https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html). I have not used the tools mentioned there, but I will probably try them out soon.  I believe that this article can shed some light on the second part of your question.